# Prove if $v \in \text{span}(S)$, then $ \text{span}(S) = \text{span}(S ∪ \{v\})$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

> Suppose $S$ is  a  subset  of  a  vector  space $V$.  Show  that  if $v\in \text{span}(S)$,  then  $\text{span}(S)  =  \text{span}(S ∪ \{v\})$

Any help is appreciated. I don't even know where to start really, thanks for your time!

Comment: Start by unpacking the statement. First of all, what does it mean for $v$ to be in $\operatorname{span}(S)$? What is $\operatorname{span}(S)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $S\subseteq S\cup\{v\}$ it's clear that $span(S)\subseteq span(S\cup\{v\})$. For other hand, $S\subseteq span(S)$ and $v\in span(S)$ implies that any linear combination between elements of $S$ and $v$ lies in $span(S)$, i.e., $span(S\cup\{v\})\subseteq span(S)$.